# How can I call a Laravel function from html?

Tags: php, laravel

I want this html code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="company_policy_file_path">Policy File Path<span class="required"> : (Required Field)</span></label>
    <input id="company_policy_file_path" type="text" name="file_path" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter the file path" />
</div>
```

to upload file to the backend and execute this laravel function

```
<?php
    echo Form::open(array('url' => '/uploadfile','files'=>'true'));
    echo 'Select the file to upload.';
    echo Form::file('image');
?>
```

Can anyone give me suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: in laravel it open a form. What do you really wants to do ?

Comment: inspect and check you can see `html` from **Laravel form**

Comment: i want to replace the upload file function to the current form-group

Comment: Means you want the above html content in laravel context. right?

Answer (score 1):

```
{{Form::open(['url' => '/uploadfile', 'files' => true])}}

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('company_policy_file_path', 'Policy File Path<span class="required"> : (Required Field)</span>')}}
    {{Form::text('file_path', '', ['id' => 'company_policy_file_path', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Please Enter the file path'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('image', 'Select the file to upload.')}}
    {{Form::file('image', array('id' => 'image'))}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}
</div>

{{Form::close()}}
```